# What is supply.locked in the blockfrost API /network endpoint?

Tags: blockfrost

I have been working on a data analytics on Cardano using blockfrost. I am fairly familiar with Cardano tokenomics, but I have been wondering about the supply.locked data in the /network endpoint. Here is the description in the github

[image]

> locked property to /network endpoint, representing total supply locked by scripts

Does this represent the value locked in Cardano by smart contracts + timelocked contracts (aka. scripts)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct, it is the amount of ADA locked by contracts.

On [docs.blockfrost.io](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Network):
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I still cannot upvote. So this is the best I can do. Hopefully, I should have something for the community soon.